# Is PDF an XML format?

Tags: xml, pdf, pdf-generation

I was intrigued by a question for a long time :
If PDF is XML
why can't I simply create a PDF document by simply adhering to XML rules
by setting elements, and attributes, proper nesting ... etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If PDF is XML why can't I simply...

PDF is **not** XML.

To generate PDF from XML, use XSLT to convert the XML to XSL:FO, which can then be rendered to PDF by an XSL-FO processor such as Apache FOP, Antenna House, or RenderX.

Comment: I concur with kjhughes, PDF is not XML. XML is XML.\

Comment: May be you're right,well I'm sure you are. But PDF isn't made of tags too?

Comment: [**No**](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

Comment: pdf optionally allows tags to be added to its page drawing command streams. But these tags **(a)** don't have any influence on how data is displayed and **(b)** are not the same as xml elements (even though they often are named similar to html elements).

Answer (score 2):

Even if PDF were XML, you wouldn't want to write the code to create it by hand. Deciding how to flow linear text into rectangular areas in a way that is visually appealing requires specialist tools. There's a world of difference between XML tagged to say "this is a paragraph" and XML (or any other format) tagged to say "use slightly looser kerning between the letters on this line to produce a nicely justified right margin".